# Drools.net call function in LHS of the rule

Tags: .net, drools

I am trying to use drools.Net for my project , but i have some difficulties when writing the rules , especially the LHS part of the rule, I couldn't find a way to call a function of my class in the LHS part.

I want to do like this:

when

p: Problem(Value == "true", testMethod() == true)

testMethod is a function in Problem class and it returns a boolean. but this is not working and i didn't find any documentation or examples related to this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Regards,

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that this is Drools.net. A very old Drools. Perhaps you can call `testMethod` in an eval: `p: Problem(...) eval( p.testMethod() )`.

Comment: that doesn't work either